# How to make Logger write to file while Python script is running

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have the following code inside my script to create a log of all the prints that the script does in the console:

```
import sys    
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pathLogs = 'logs/'
        if not os.path.isdir(pathLogs):
            os.makedirs(pathLogs)
        file_name = pathLogs + "logger.log"
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(file_name, "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)
sys.stdout = Logger()
```

It works fine, but it prints everything to a file only after the script is finished. It is not printing anything while the script is running, even though I do see my prints in the console. How can I make it not wait until the end of the script to start printing to a my log file?

Comment: I would bet that Python's file objects use an internal buffer, so you need to call `flush()` to force the write to happen.  Alternatively, just use the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: or just run your script with `python myscript.py > output.txt`

Comment: @0x5453 Could you post an answer with the code using the logging module to replace the above code?

Comment: @crookedleaf I tried your suggestion, but it is the same thing. Nothing gets printed to output.txt until the script run is complete.

Comment: @sprogissd if you want realtime text output, then definitely just use python's [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) library as @0x5453 pointed out. It's really easy to find tutorials on how to build a logging handler. Once you do, just replace your `print` statements with logging statements.